# How to use each value of a std::set as a key of a map

Tags: c++, string, c++11, stdmap

Assume we have a map with `int` and set of `strings`

```
std::map < int , std::set<std::string> >  myString;

1=> "set1"
1=> "set2"
2=> "set1"
2=> "set2"
```

Now, is it possible to make each unique value of the above set as a map key
Roughly, data would be like

```
1=>
  set1=> "Hello"
  set1=> "Hey"
  set1=> "Wow"
1=>  
  set2=> "Hello"
  set2=> "Hey"
  set2=> "Wow"
2=>

  set1=> "Hello"
  set1=> "Hey"
  set1=> "Wow"
2=>  
  set2=> "Hello"
  set2=> "Hey"
  set2=> "Wow"
```

In plain words, I am trying to design a map which has an integer key pointing to set of strings and each string again has multiple values, thus i thought of a set of string as a plain string to integer would overwrite the values and we would just have single final value.

I dont think the below syntax would solve the issue:

```
std::map < std::set<std::string>, std::string >  myString;
```

You advice would be really helpful, as I am trying to break the bigger problem into short and will join all these sub problems.

Sorry if my explanation is bad and confusing.
Here is the code i tried

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

struct values
{
    std::string a;
    std::string b;
    values():a("milepost"),b("dummyval"){};
    values( std::string ab, std::string bc)
    {
        a=ab;
        b=bc;

    };
    bool operator<(const values& other) const { return a< other.a;}

};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    //Create set of types firstly
    std::set<std::string> types ;
    types.insert("et");
    types.insert("pt");

    typedef std::map< int,std::set<std::string> > myGroupsMap;
    typedef std::map<std::string,values>  myWsData;
    typedef std::map< std::string , std::set<myWsData> > myFinalData;
    typedef std::map< int,std::set<myFinalData> > myGroupData;


    //Create the group  with all types in each of them
   // groupname  type
   //    1        et
   //    2        et
   //    1        pt
   //    2        pt

    myGroupsMap groupTypeMap;

    groupTypeMap.insert(std::make_pair(1, types) );


 groupTypeMap.insert(std::make_pair(2, types) );
    groupTypeMap.insert(std::make_pair(3, types) );
    groupTypeMap.insert(std::make_pair(4, types) );
    groupTypeMap.insert(std::make_pair(5, types) );

    //Create the object of structure
    values a,b,c;

    //Create map and insert the string and its corresponding structure
    myWsData et_Data1,pt_Data2;
    et_Data1.insert(std::make_pair("780256", a));
et_Data1.insert(std::make_pair("780255", b));
et_Data1.insert(std::make_pair("780254", c));

pt_Data2.insert(std::make_pair("780256", a));
pt_Data2.insert(std::make_pair("780255", b));
pt_Data2.insert(std::make_pair("780254", c));

std::set<myWsData> myet_pt_data;
myet_pt_data.insert(et_Data1);
myet_pt_data.insert(pt_Data2);



  myFinalData fd , fd1 , fd2 ;
    fd.insert(std::make_pair ("ET",myet_pt_data) );
    fd.insert(std::make_pair ("PT",myet_pt_data) );

    fd1.insert(std::make_pair ("ET",myet_pt_data) );
    fd1.insert(std::make_pair ("PT",myet_pt_data) );

    fd2.insert(std::make_pair ("ET",myet_pt_data) );
    fd2.insert(std::make_pair ("PT",myet_pt_data) );


    std::set<myFinalData> mfd;
    mfd.insert(fd);
    mfd.insert(fd1);
    mfd.insert(fd2);


    myGroupData mygd;
    mygd.insert(std::make_pair (1,mfd) );
    mygd.insert(std::make_pair (2,mfd) );
    mygd.insert(std::make_pair (3,mfd) );


    return 0;

 }
```

Thanks.
Tejas

Comment: You cannot have two elements with the same key in a map, for example "1=> "set1",1=> "set2",2=> "set1",2=> "set2"" is not a map

Comment: It is possible with a map and key  1 can have both values set1 and set2 as per example .  My issue is having each value of this value set  acting as a map key std::map<int,std::set<std::string>>

Comment: We can definitely have numerous elements per key and the trick is std::set

Comment: so you actually mean  1=> {"set1","set2"},2=> {"set1","set2"} ? and do you maybe want a `map<int, set< map<string,vector<string>>>>`?

Comment: well ,i  meant 1=>{set1=>"7802"=>some c structure}, 2=>{set1=>"7802"=>some c structure} ,1=>{set2=>"7802"=>some c structure},...,45=>{set1=>"7802"=>some c structure}   , thanks

Comment: Also am confused of how to initialise it. Appreciate your help

Comment: I dont understand negative comments in this, is it not understandable, the problem statement is clear i assume , unless you tell me whats the issue , how would i learn, or atleast try to tell me whats the issue and down vote it. Just down voting the post would not help me a bit in understanding what is the issue and i would not learn too

Comment: @tobi303 : is nt it clearly stated in the post , i have  written in the first line code `std::map < int , std::set<std::string> >  myString;`
which iam sure means an int withe set of string values .

Comment: I sense that you feel offended, that was not my intention. And no, for me it wasnt clear from the question, otherwise I would not ask ;)

Comment: btw I dont see any negative comments, just some downvotes that most likely are caused by the fact that your question does not contain code, but lots of text. Problems with code are best expressed via code (and maybe the resulting error messages) rather than long text

Comment: see also here: [mcve]

Comment: Your question is not clear at all, but here's a stab in the dark. Perhaps what you want is 2 separate maps. 1) `map<int, set<string>>` and 2) `map<string, SomeStruct>` -- Where the strings contained in the sets of the first map are used as keys in the second map. Does that make sense, and could it possibly apply to the problem you are trying to solve? I honestly have no idea if it does, because like I said, your question is very unclear.

Comment: @tobi303 ,@benjamin : sure but the code i ve tried writing but .  with no feedback actually , so broke the issue into a smaller subproblem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43028301/how-to-make-each-value-of-a-map-of-int-and-stdset-point-to-a-map                                                   Thanks for your comments

Comment: @BenjaminLindley , I ve tried the solution you specified , but i wasn't able to figure out how to have a relation between both, that would definitely be helpful , you can see the solution i tried is similar to you advice http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43028301/how-to-make-each-value-of-a-map-of-int-and-stdset-point-to-a-map , but i am unable to form a link between both (string in a set pointing to other hash )

Comment: I am sorry, but also the other question I didnt really understand. I think it would really help if you would write a smaller example with what you would like to do and report the error you get. Maybe then it will be easier to help you fix it

Comment:  will post code in a bit , please let me know how to relate both the maps

Comment: This looks line an XY problem. Can you describe the real problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

> map which has an integer key pointing to set of strings and each string again has multiple values

If I just take this literally and assume "multiple values" refers to some custom type, then I would maybe come up with something like this:

```
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct Foo{
        int _id;
        Foo(int id):_id(id){}
        bool operator<(const Foo& other) const { return _id < other._id;}
};

typedef std::vector<Foo>                      multiple_values;
typedef std::string                           each_string;
typedef std::map<each_string,multiple_values> again_has;
typedef std::set<again_has>                   set_of_strings_and;
typedef std::map<int,set_of_strings_and>      map_which_has;

int main(){
    multiple_values    mv   = {Foo(1),Foo(2)};
    again_has          ah   = {{"test",mv}};
    set_of_strings_and sosa = {ah};
    map_which_has      mwh  = {{0,sosa}};
};
```

Comment: please see the code update i have done. it doesn't compile in mac and doesn't show any errors too.i have to update my Xcode i suppose

Comment: am sorry that i have literally lost in breaking through this problem and am more confused with my code now :) , thanks for ur support

Comment: And can u explain why have u overloaded operator < , that exactly is the issue with my code

Comment: And as per ur code , my requirement would be 0=>sosa=>"test0"=>structure   , 1=>sosa=>"test1"=>structure ,  1=>sasa=>"test2"=>structure   , 2=>sosa=>"test3"=>structure                           Apologies for the  {} , am new to this actually , but apparently 1 has 2 values (sosa and sasa )

Comment: @LearningCpp not 100% atm, but I think it was the `set` that needs the `operator<` to check if two elements are equivalent

Comment: @LearningCpp well you added the code to the quesiton, now you just have to add what is wrong with that code, ie the error message. Not sure how it can not compile when there are no errors. Maybe you are just looking at the wrong output console?

Comment: would u help me understand why we need operator < overloaded here

Comment: @LearningCpp because the set (as containers in general) uses `!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)` to check if two elements are equivalent, where `comp` by default is the `operator<`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139127/discussion-between-learningcpp-and-tobi303).